# Share post in Linkedin

Tags: share, linkedin-api

I am trying to share a post with LinkedIn.

[image: share on LinkedIn]

After sharing the post on LinkedIn. There is only a single letter **M** displaying instead of full page title.

Anyone can suggest how can I display complete page title?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to your webpage and view source, you see that the `title` tag is the following:

```
<title>Méditation pour le Ressourcement,et l'Aide à la Décision</title>
```

The letter M is followed by an accented e (`é`) and so it wasn't known whether it is part of the standard header or a punctuation or an end of line / end of sentence.

You can mitigate this by implementing open graph by adding the following `meta` tag to the header of your website / webpage:

```
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:title" content="Méditation pour le Ressourcement,et l'Aide à la Décision"/>
```

The `og:title` in particular is the open graph implementation and is more consistent: it makes sure your share snippets across all social media and websites (that uses the open graph protocol) come up consistently.

If that is not a possibility (adding a custom tag in your header) then the less-consistent fix is to replace the accented characters so that your title uses only the standard letters:

```
<title>Meditation pour le Ressourcement, et l'Aide a la Decision</title>
```